# phpMyAdmin bzip2 for exports

Tags: phpmyadmin

MySQL version  = 5.5.39, PHP Version = 5.4.32, on Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

I was using and old phpMyAdmin ver 2.11.9.6 and bzip2 was successfully being used for my exports on a daily basis. However, I switched to the new phpMyAdmin ver 4.4.15.5 and I no longer see that bzip2 is an available export compression option.

I have added $cfg['BZipDump'] = true and $cfg['CompressOnFly'] = true in my config.inc.php file. However, it still does not show bzip2 as a compression option for exports on the newest version of phpMyAdmin.

BZip2 Support is enabled and bzip2 is a valid stream in my php version and the bzopen() and bzcompress() functions do indeed exist in php, as I have manually confirmed their existence.

Any help would be great to show me how to allow bzip2 on the new version of phpMyAdmin.